# Opening "data:xxx" URLs in Safari

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I'm failing to open data URL:s in iOS/Safari.

```
NSString* stringUrl = @"data:text/html;base64,PGh0bWw+DQo8Ym9keT4NCjxzY3JpcHQgbGFuZ3VhZ2U9IkphdmFTY3JpcHQiPg0KZG9jdW1lbnQubG9jYXRpb249J2h0dHA6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbSc7DQo8L3NjcmlwdD4NCjwvYm9keT4NCjwvaHRtbD4=";
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];
NSLog(@"Got url: %@", url);
const BOOL STATUS = [UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:url];
NSLog(@"STATUS: %d", STATUS);
```

This is supposed to open Safari on an iOS device. The resulting page would be:

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
document.location='http://www.google.com';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However openURL fails, STATUS returns NO/0. How do we fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the stringUrl is correct?

Comment: Yes it generates a NSURL instead of nil. You can try `data:text/html;base64,PGh0bWw+DQo8Ym9keT4NCjxzY3JpcHQgbGFuZ3VhZ2U9IkphdmFTY3JpcHQiPg0KZG9jdW1lbnQubG9jYXRpb249J2h0dHA6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbSc7DQo8L3NjcmlwdD4NCjwvYm9keT4NCjwvaHRtbD4=` in any browser, it will generate that page and relocate to google.

Comment: I managed to do it but in a pretty long-winded way... I had to implement a web server into the app itself and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can use special method of UIApplication to determine if it can open your URL or not

BOOL STATUS = [UIApplication.sharedApplication **canOpenURL**:url];

However, there is no mention in documentation if UIApplication is capable to open URL with "data" scheme:

*"UIKit supports many schemes, including http, https, tel, facetime, and mailto schemes."* - from documentation for UIApplication.

You can attempt to open this URL in internal UIWebView browser and see how it goes with this method of UIWebView:

```
- (void)loadData:(NSData *)data MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType textEncodingName:(NSString *)encodingName baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL;
```

Comment: I have not tried the path with UIWebView but I managed to do it in another way. The main problem with UIApplication/openURL is it cannot directly open very long URLs, and in this case very long URLs are pretty normal if they contain just a few images or even just one image. The problem is not with Safari in iOS. You can try to paste that data:xxx line manually in iPhone Safari and you will see it works.