# Open Url "data:text/html;base64, base64string" In Safari from iOS application

Tags: ios, openurl

I want to redirect a base64 url to safari with openURL method.
But, I can not do that. 
Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641461/iphone-open-data-url-in-safari and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672873/opening-dataxxx-urls-in-safari

Comment: its not working. I have already read it.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I think there is no solution to do this without a webserver. If you're ok with this, this small class could help you:

[OpenBase64EncodedDataWithSafari](https://github.com/HerrmDE/OpenBase64EncodedDataWithSafari)

It works fine on the device, but perhaps not at the iOS Simulator.